# how to click hidden sub menu(mouse hover) in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, hidden-field

I want to click invisible html's sub menu click.

*invisible html source

[image]

```
<ul class="options">
<li class="_ranking-attr-filter-container _sub-menu-target">
<span>Hide work using these filters</span>
</li></ul>
```

*my code

```
element_to_hover_over = _Driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[contains(@class, 'sub-menu-target')]")
hover = ActionChains(_Driver).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over).perform()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, unicode("男", errors='replace')))).click()  #this line don't working. 10061 socket error.
```

my code's mouse hover part is working, but sub menu's click don't working.
but sub menu's kanji is invisible in html(can't find id, class name), I don't know how to select sub menu.

I tried this, but don't work(UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode blarblar...)

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@type="checkbox"][contains(text(), "男")]'))).click()
```

just choosing first submenu by selenium is impossible?
I need your advise, thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to click mouse over sub menu in selenium?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41795013/how-to-click-mouse-over-sub-menu-in-selenium)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice.

Comment: sorry, but I still couldn't find the solution.